# How to process multiple files inside a Pool on multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to process multiple images from separate files, for example, I am trying to process 3 folders, which each one contains 8 Satellite images and for each image I am doing 4 separate atmospheric corrections (math equations) then save them with different names.

Previously I have been able to apply `Pool` tool from `Multiprocessing` for 1 folder.

from main script I use this function to call the processing function for each folder

```
def proceso_lotes(self, path):
    #Flags to choose which atmospheric correction use
    rad  = self.v12.get()
    ref  = self.v22.get()
    dos1 = self.v32.get()
    dos2 = self.v42.get()
    ndvi = self.v52.get()

    start_time = time.time()

    for num_file in range(len(self.new_files)):  #self.new_files is the list that contains the folder name
        print()
        print("Archivo #: ", num_file)
        print("Ruta: ", path)
        print("Nombre de archivo: ", self.new_files[num_file])
        path_mtdt=os.path.join(path, self.new_files[num_file],self.new_files[num_file]+"_MTL.txt" )
        print("Ruta de mtdt: ", path_mtdt)

        #This are the functions that uses the multiprocessing option,
        if rad:
            radiancia_lote(path_mtdt)
        if ref:
            reflectancia_lote(path_mtdt)
        if dos1:
            toados1_lote(path_mtdt)
        if dos2:
            toados2_lote(path_mtdt)


print('TIEMPO TOTAL DE CALCULOS::')
print((time.time() - start_time))
```

And in the example let's call `radiancia_lote` that is a function in another script

```
def radiancia_lote(archivo):

    start_time = time.time()
    print("Archivo: ")
    print(archivo)

    p = Pool(processes=cpu_count())
    p.map(partial(procesar_bandas, archivos=archivo), range(1, 8))
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print('TOTAL TIME TO RAD:')
    print((time.time() - start_time))
```

Here is where I use the `Pool` function and works great for 1 file (4 seconds approx), after that I check the Windows Task Manager and I don't see the cores working and next file takes up to 70seconds or more, like if `Pool` doesn't start again.

Can I make a `Pool` function that opens the 3 folders at the same time then call another `Pool` to process as much images before all the cores are full? I hope I made my idea clear.
Or I need to use `Pool` and `Threads` to achieve that task?
I am kinda new on `Multiprocessing` on python

I am using Python 3.5

Comment: It makes little sense to have `Pool`s of `Pool`s. Generally, the cheap or inherently serial work should be done in the main process anyway; even if you had multiple stages of parallelizable work, it makes more sense to use a single `Pool` (occupying all cores) for all stages. The problem here looks like you're creating pools over and over, and using them in a way likely to leave gaps where they go unused (waiting for the first full `map` to finish, even if only a single task is incomplete, rather than making sure new work is available for the idle workers).

Comment: Also, a warning: pickling a `functools.partial` instance involves pickling all the bound arguments, and it has to be done for *every* worker. If `archivo` is an expensive object to pickle/transmit (e.g. has a huge pickled form), then you're paying that cost over and over for *every* task, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it's there any other way  to add `args` instead of `functools.partial`?

Comment: Yup, the old-fashioned way: Define a global function that calls the wrapped function using the extra argument. Make sure the extra argument is stored in a global variable, and stored before the `Pool` is created (and on Windows, it would need to be initialized and stored during module load, and might not work at all, since Windows only simulates `fork`, and can't simulate it very well).